# Modify ELF section using libelf?

Tags: c, elf

I'm writing a program that adds a section to an elf binary using libelf. Is there a way to modify the contents of the shstrndx?

Comment: Sure; in the worst case you can use `libelf` to create a complete ELF file from scratch.  Do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

I think this example [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=elfutils.git;a=blob;f=tests/addsections.c;h=c1b0fa81f5acaf7d586d769ab923934de314458f;hb=HEAD), found in the main repo of `libelf`, is exactly what you are looking for.